# Exact phrase matching in open search server

Tags: search-engine, opensearch

I need to match an exact phrase in open search server.

which means "Master of business administration" should not match the keyword "business" or "Master" or "administration" or "of".

I need exactly matched results only.

Is it possible using open search server.??

Answer (score 4):

OpenSearchServer uses Lucene as back-end. It supports the same syntax. The double quote applies a proximity query. It means that it look for close words. You can also add a distance tolerance between words (phrase slop), using this syntax:

```
"master business administration"~2
```

That way "master OF business administration" will be find. The default phrase slop is 10.

About exact spelling, it depends on which field you apply the search. On a standard OpenSearchServer template, you have two fields: content and contentExact.
"content" stores a "lemmmatized + lowercase" version of the words: "mast of busing administr"

It means you could find: "masterING of business administrATIVE".
"contentExact" stored a lowercase version of the words, keeping the original spelling.

To force using one field use the semicolon syntax:

```
contentExact:"master of business administration"
```

You can also mix both parameters:

```
contentExact:"master of business administration"~2
```

You can change the default query of OpenSearchServer as well as the semantical filters applied to fields using the web interface.

I hope this help.